# Polymer StarterKit doesn't work on PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, polymer, phonegap-cli

I'm trying to Create Android PhoneGap using   [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org) ,it is worked very well on browser http://192.168.1.2:8080/ , But don't work on the phone

code `Polymer Starter Kit`

**`index.php`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My App description">


    <script>
      // Setup Polymer options
      window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow',
        lazyRegister: true,
      };

      // Load webcomponentsjs polyfill if browser does not support native
      // Web Components
      (function() {
        'use strict';

        var onload = function() {
          // For native Imports, manually fire WebComponentsReady so user code
          // can use the same code path for native and polyfill'd imports.
          if (!window.HTMLImports) {
            document.dispatchEvent(
              new CustomEvent('WebComponentsReady', {bubbles: true})
            );
          }
        };

        var webComponentsSupported = (
          'registerElement' in document
          && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
          && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
        );

        if (!webComponentsSupported) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.async = true;
          script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
          script.onload = onload;
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        } else {
          onload();
        }
      })();

      // Load pre-caching Service Worker
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
        });
      }
    </script>

    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <!-- Built with love using Polymer Starter Kit -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**`/src/my-app.html`**`:`

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-icons.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;

        display: block;
      }

      app-header {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
      }
      app-header paper-icon-button {
        --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
      }

      .drawer-list {
        margin: 0 20px;
      }

      .drawer-list a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: var(--app-secondary-color);
        line-height: 40px;
      }

      .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>

    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer id="drawer">
        <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
          <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
          <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
          <a name="view3" href="/view3">View Three</a>
          <a name="new-view" href="/view">New View</a>
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>My App</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <iron-pages
            selected="[[page]]"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="view404"
            role="main">
          <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
          <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
          <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
          <my-view name="view"></my-view>
          <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged',
        },
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';

        if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
        }
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with using absolute paths vs relative paths & is kind of a complicated issue (see https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/919 as an entry point for more details).

To just get things working you should be able to change this line in your index file:

```
script.src = '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
```

to

```
script.src = 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js';
```

However you'll possibly then need some changes to your app routing when running on Cordova, but see if this gets you started.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved for me. Thanks.

But, the app stills unstable in some parts and the home routing doesn't work. An app built using this conversion should be well tested to not break sensible parts.